# Distance query for arbitary points with GeoDjango not working as expected - distance calculation seem off

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I'm building a world-map and want users to be able to look-up locations and have them be sorted by distance from anywhere in the world. I'm using GeoDjango to calculate distances, however, the distances returned seemed wrong so I checked them against `geopy`'s calculations.

The distances differ significantly to the point that if the results are sorted by the DB distance values in kilometers vs `geopy` values in km they would not be in the same order.

I'm assuming the `geopy` values are correct so I'm wondering, is there something wrong with the way I implemented GeoDjango?

Is it working as it should? 
Does this have something to do with trying to calculate distances for the entire world and not just a specific area which could have a `srid`?

`views.py`

```
pnt = GEOSGeometry('POINT({} {})'.format(latitude, longitude), srid=4326)
qs = Place.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=radius*2))).annotate(distance=Distance('point', pnt)).order_by('distance')
```

`settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'USER': '',
        'NAME': 'places',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from geopy.distance import vincenty

class Place(models.Model):
        latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
        longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
        point = models.PointField(null=True, geography=True)

    def distance_from_target(self, target_lat, target_lon):
        if not target_lat or not target_lon:
            return None
        instance_point = (self.latitude, self.longitude)
        target_point = (target_lat, target_lon)
        return vincenty(instance_point, target_point).kilometers
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to multiply radius * 2!

I was facing also a differences between postgres/postgis calculated distance and the distance from `geopy.distance.vincenty`, but very small one (on meters level not kilometers)

I do my querying like this

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance as DistanceFun
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr

user_location = fromstr(
    "POINT({value_lon} {value_lat})".format(value_lon=value_lon, value_lat=value_lat)
)
qs.filter(
    location__distance_lte=(user_location, Distance(m=value_radius_in_meters))
).annotate(
    distance=DistanceFun('location', user_location)
).order_by('distance')
```